# In Canada, is there a requirement of when a Money Services Business (MSB) and their client entity must enter into a service agreement?

Tags: canada, terms-of-service, finance, money-laundering, money-service

I hope the question in the title lends itself to an answer. In case more clarification is required, please do not hesitate to comment below.

Some background: In Canada, an MSB is required to verify the existence of an entity when they enter into a service agreement because it is then that the MSB is required to keep a Client Information Record on the MSB which triggers the existence verification. (See last question here: https://www.fintrac-canafe.gc.ca/guidance-directives/overview-apercu/FINS/2-eng?s=7)

It seems natural to me that The Financial Transactions and Reports Analysis Centre of Canada (FINTRAC) should have a requirement of when to have a service agreement because otherwise one is under no obligation to perform the existence verification or obtain beneficial ownership  which is important to prevent Money Laundering and Terrorist Financing. But I was unable to find anything on it.

Comment: How does a Main Switch Board (MSB) enter into agreements? It’s a piece of electrical equipment. If you use acronyms you have to tell us what they mean - we all have different backgrounds and come from different parts of the world - your acronym and mine are different.

Comment: @DaleM Haha. A wake up call that I should not use acronyms without introducing them. Let me edit it.

Comment: @DaleM My apologies.

Comment: you’ve still left us with an unexplained FINTRAC and ML/TF

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo generally, when the law is at stake, we prefer not to guess.

Comment: @DaleM  Pardon me for the assumptions I made. Hope I've corrected all of them now.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the comments. I am not a lawyer. But I think introducing acronyms applies across fields. I have learnt something useful.